# Liskov Substitution and SRP Principle violation - how best to structure this scenario?

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

While learning SRP and LSP, I'm trying to improve the design of my code to comply best with both of these principles. I have an employee class that has a calculatePay method on it. Firstly, I believe following OOP SOLID Principles, calculatePay() method should not be an employee objects responsibility. Common responsibilities of employees would be to performDuties(), takeLunchBreak(), clockIn() and clockOut() etc.. Am I right in thinking this way? That's why I feel calculatePay() should belong in some other class. Okay so that's my SRP insecurity.

Coming to LSP:

I have subclasses like accountants, salesman, and directors. These are all employees that get paid. How would I change this design to better support volunteers? Volunteers don't get paid.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private boolean topPerformer;
    private int bonusAmount;


    public Employee(String name, int salary, boolean topPerformer, int bonusAmount) {
       // set fields etc..
    }

    // This method doesn't seem to belong here.
    public int calculatePay(){
        if(topPerformer)
            return salary+bonusAmount;
         else{
            return salary;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a payment of 0 for volunteers be acceptable? Otherwise, what about a sub-type `PayedEmployee` (probably an interface).

Comment: No a zero would be a bad Idea. I don't want to potentially mail home a check to a volunteer employee with 0$ on it. that would be quite a shame. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually dealing with a number of distinct entities here.

The first entity is the employee - which you've got.

The second entity is the payment structure. As you saw, the initial code seemed straightforward until you added a volunteer to the mix.

The third is the payment calculation - salaried employees get paid differently depending on their performance, while a volunteer gets no money.

Life gets more interesting when you consider that different employees could have different contractual relationships with their employer, which means that they have the same "payment structure" but their end payment is different. Second, an employee could fit into multiple categories at the same time - a salaried employee could also do volunteer work - which is an additional reason why you need to split out the "payment structure" and "payment calculation" into their classes.

To implement these concepts -

First, move the payment structure  into it's own class by add a "paymentstructure" class, like so:

```
public PaymentStructure(salary, 
                        boolean topPerformer, 
                        int bonusAmount) {       
    // set properties for a salaried employee etc..
}

public PaymentStructure() {// default constructor = volunteer employee 
                           // set salary, bonusamount to 0, topPerformer to false, etc..
}
```

Doing this also allows for adding other types of payment calculation inputs - such as for lump-sum payments when a job is done, etc.

Next, if you're only allowing for a single payment relationship with an employee, you need to change the employee constructor to accept the payment structure:

```
public Employee(String name, PaymentStructure PayStructureParm)
   // Save PayStructureParm to a class property 
}
```

and then write a class to implement the payment calculation logic:

```
public DeterminePayment(){
   public float calculatePayment(PaymentStructure PayStructureParm) { 
            // logic to turn the payment structure into a final payment 
     return finalPayment; }
}
```

This splits the employee, payment structure, and payment calculation into their own classes all of which can then be extended as required.

For even more flexibility, each of these classes could coded against an interface, and specific types of payment structure and calculation classes coded against their respective interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, Employee should not be able to calculate their own salary. You would never ask an employee to do so. In your design, I would create a PayrollService class that calculates an employee's salary and a DisbursementService that knows when and how to send a check. Following the SOLID principles to their exact definitions is sometimes difficult.

Hope I correctly understood your question.